# Does the documentation mention the possibility of adding the `mut` keyword in front of functions' arguments?

Tags: rust, mutability, function-signature

I have a basic `Reader` encapsulating some generic elements:

```
pub struct Reader<R> {
    inner: R,
    order: Endian,
    first_ifd_offset: usize,
}

impl<R: Read + Seek> Reader<R> {
    pub fn new(reader: R) -> Result<Reader<R>> {
        let mut order_raw = [0, 0];
        reader.read_exact(&mut order_raw)?;
        let magic_number = u16::to_be(u16::from_bytes(order_raw));
        /* ... */
   }
}
```

This does not compile and produces the following error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable argument `reader` as mutable
  --> src/reader.rs:17:9
   |
15 |     pub fn new(reader: R) -> Result<Reader<R>> {
   |                ------ consider changing this to `mut reader`
16 |         let mut order_raw = [0, 0];
17 |         reader.read_exact(&mut order_raw)?;
   |         ^^^^^^ cannot borrow mutably
```

As I am getting the argument by value, the `new` function should be the new owner of the `reader` element. The compiler advises me to to add a `mut` keyword in front of the function argument.

Does the documentation mention the possibility of adding the `mut` keyword in front of functions' arguments? I was not able to find resources mentioning it.

The `BufReader` struct of the standard library has a
similar `new` function and does not use a `mut` keyword but an `unsafe`
block code in the body. Does `unsafe` prevent the usage of `mut` inside the function's signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the compiler is very precise in saying where to add the `mut`. Generally the compiler tries to underline the specific places:

```
pub fn new(mut reader: R) -> Result<Reader<R>>
```

It's now possible to mutate the reader in the function. This behaves like:

```
pub fn new(reader: R) -> Result<Reader<R>, Error> {
    let mut reader = reader;
    // ...
```

As far as I know, it's only [mentioned once](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/mutability.html#mutability) in the book but more or less in sense of *It's a pattern, you may use it in functions too*.

[`unsafe` does not fix it, it's UB](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html):

> Mutating non-mutable data — that is, data reached through a shared reference or data owned by a `let` binding), unless that data is contained within an [`UnsafeCell<U>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html).

Comment: Just to confirm, in the case of `BufReader`, this is not needed due to the fact that no `mutable` function of the inner `Read` object is called inside the `new` function. If such a call is made later but wrapped in another `BufRead` `&mut self` function, we assume we acquired mutability for all the field the `BufRead` struct has acquired?

Comment: @yageek If I get your comment right, this is true, yes.

Answer (score 3):

It’s implied but not directly mentioned in the book. Both `let` and function arguments are patterns, so just like you can use `mut` in `let`, you can use it in arguments.

Comment: Just to confirm, in the case of `BufReader`, this is not needed due to the fact that no `&mut ref` function of the inner `Read` object is called inside the `new` function. If such a call is made later but wrapped in another `BufRead` `&mut self` function, we assume we acquired mutability for all the field the BufRead struct has acquired?